# How can I move items in a combobox to a listbox using a generic method

Tags: c#, wpf, object, combobox, listbox

This is my first post so please be patient. Using C# I have a Windows form with a combo box and a list box and want to move items from one object to the other. I am trying to create a method where I can pass these objects and have an algorithm do the work based on which object is passed first. Here is what I have so far and the algorithm works elsewhere in my code (when I explicitly state Combobox1 instead of Obj1, or Listbox1 instead of Obj2) but I want to remove it from the methods its in and create its own method to allow for movement of list items for any type of object that holds list items, such as Listbox, Combobox, etc... Visual Studios is saying that Obj1 and Obj2 do not exist in the current context, I think because they are defined within the if block, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void UpdateSelectionListing(object MoveFilesTo, object MoveFilesFrom)
    {
        /* Identify what object will have items moved to, 
         * and what objects will have items moved from */ 
        if (MoveFilesTo is ComboBox && MoveFilesFrom is ListBox)
            {
                ComboBox Obj1 = (ComboBox)MoveFilesTo;
                ListBox Obj2 = (ListBox)MoveFilesFrom;
            }
        else if (MoveFilesTo is ListBox && MoveFilesFrom is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox Obj2 = (ComboBox)MoveFilesTo;
                ListBox Obj1 = (ListBox)MoveFilesFrom;
            }

        for (int n = Obj1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                Obj2.Items.Add(Obj1.Items[n].ToString());
                Obj1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the instances inside if conditions, that makes it an **obvious error**.Also, you can make it easier as below:

```
private void UpdateSelectionListing(object MoveFilesTo, object MoveFilesFrom)
 {
     ItemsControl ToObj=MoveFilesTo as ItemsControl;
     ItemsControl FromObj=MoveFilesFrom as ItemsControl;
     List<string> resultList=new List<string>();
      foreach (var item in FromObj.Items)
      {
         resultList.Add(item.ToString());
      }
      FromObj.ItemsSource=null;
      ToObj.ItemsSOurce=resultList;
      FromObj.Items.Refresh();
      ToObj.Items.Refresh();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I must be doing something wrong because once I added the code and tested it, It tells me I need to add multiple references; The error is something like this -- "The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" I've added these references PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, And WindowsBase and it just keeps giving me a new error. Any ideas???

Comment: do you have 'System.Windows.Markup added to references?

Comment: Yes, I added all the references (including PresentationCore) its telling me I'm missing. Here is the complete error reference for it...    
The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Again thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to the question of the references in your project.

Comment: I've got the references fixed, i think, but now its giving me an error in the for loop saying FromObj is not set to an instance of an object. Like it hasn't been instantiated. I tried below but it didn't work either...
{
 ItemsControl ToObj = new ItemsControl();
 ItemsControl FromObj = new ItemsControl();

 ToObj = MoveFilesTo as ItemsControl;
 FromObj = MoveFilesFrom as ItemsControl;
...
}

Comment: there a lot of problems/Exceptions in your approach.what about bindings/MVVM.do you have knowledge about these?

Comment: No I don't have knowledge of bindings/MVVM. I'll make some screen shots and upload them in the morning. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, the updated answer worked for me. but it would be better if you consider using MVVM & take advantages of Bindings.

Comment: I got the references working but even with the updated code I'm still getting "a Null Reference was unhandled" error saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm trying to figure out how to add an image to the post

Comment: just check what values are you getting for all the variables, it seems something is null.Also, are you doing anything after using this code , may be you are getting the exception from other part & not this. please add the whole code to the question.